# jQuery math operation on $(window).height() : works if division doesn't work if subtraction

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to calculate the size of an element depending on the window size.

This code works:

```
var photoHeight = function() {
    return {
        'height' : ($(window).height() / 15) + 'px'
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $obj = $('#photo');
        var photoCss = photoHeight();
        $obj.css( photoCss );
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $obj.css( photoCss );
    });
});
```

But i need to subtract instead of divide.
If i change

```
'height' : ($(window).height() / 15) + 'px'
```

to

```
'height' : ($(window).height() - 15) + 'px'
```

The value seems to be 'undefined' and no .css is applied.

The full calculation should be something like this:

```
'height' : ($(window).height() - $('#page-header').outerHeight() - $('#page-footer').outerHeight() - 50) + 'px'
```

Comment: Try Math.round($(window).height() / 15) + 'px'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `photoHeight()` function (it's simpler without):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $obj = $('#photo');
    $obj.css("height", $(window).height() / 15);
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $obj.css("height", $(window).height() / 15);
    });
});
```

Also note: if you set a variable `photoCSS` to `photoHeight()`, it won't change, even when the window resizes. If you want to use a function, go with something like `$obj.css(photoHeight());`